# Can't save persisted IGeometry object into an ObjectStream

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, c#, add-in

I was able to store a serialized `IGeometry` object into an string field in a datatable from a File Geodatabase.

For performance issues and since the object [implements](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ipersiststream.htm) `IPersistStream`, I want to save the original `IGeometry` object into a blob field.

So far I'm allowed to cast the geometry to `IPersistStream` but haven't been able to save it to an [`ObjectStream`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#objectstream.htm)

I'm using ArcObjects SDK 10.3.1. Here's the code:

```
// Insert Geometry to DataTable.
fieldIndex = errorsTable.FindField(m_dataBaseConstants.DataTables.Fields.Geometry);
IObjectStream objectStream = new ObjectStream();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry geom = dataToken.Geometry;
IPersistStream persistStream = (IPersistStream)geom;
// This line throws COMException (0x80004005)
persistStream.Save(objectStream, 0);
errorRow.Value[fieldIndex] = objectStream;
```

I have no clue why I'm not being able to save. Can you see the problem there?

Comment: you should start using the 10.x help instead of 9.2.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ipersiststream.htm

Comment: ...also, I don't see that Geometry implements IPersistStream

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Please use the code formatting button (`{}`) to indent your code to make it legible.

Comment: @Brad Thanks I've updated link references. And you are right, but IPersistStream is being implemented by Polygon, Polyline, Point... which do  implement IGeometry, right?

Comment: I think your problem is because you've got a **class** instead of an **interface**, it should be IObjectStream objectStream = new ObjectStream(); (IObjectStream is the interface, ObjectStream is the class)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson, that was a mistake but it unfortunately didn't solve the issue. I'm still unable to save and it is throwing the same old exception. I'll update the question.

Comment: Could it be as simple as a bad cast? your persist stream saves to an IStream object but you're trying to save to an IObjectStream, perhaps introduce an IStream variable (call it myStream), persistStream.Save(myStream,0); then objectStream = (IObjectStream)myStream; ... it's worth a shot. What is the exception number (HRESULT)? If it's not a general 999999 there might be some help looking up FDO error constants, or not, sometimes the description is as vague as the original error.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks for your help I do appreciate it. I've come up with a solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come with a workaround. @MichaelStimson 's comment about a potential wrong cast helped and made me think to go and just try with another stream object.

[`IMemoryBlobStream`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#imemoryblobstream.htm) just worked fine for me:

```
IMemoryBlobStream memoryBlobStream = new MemoryBlobStreamClass();
IGeometry geom = dataToken.Geometry;
IPersistStream persistStream = (IPersistStream)geom;
persistStream.Save(memoryBlobStream, 0);    
errorRow.Value[fieldIndex] = memoryBlobStream;
```

And then to unblob the persisted object to an `IGeometry`:

```
IMemoryBlobStream memoryBlobStream = new MemoryBlobStreamClass();
IPersistStream blob = default(IPersistStream);
memoryBlobStream = blobGeometry as IMemoryBlobStream;

if (geometryType.Equals(esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint.ToString()))
{
    blob = new PointClass();
}
else if (geometryType.Equals(esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline.ToString()))
{
    blob = new PolylineClass();
}
else if (geometryType.Equals(esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon.ToString()))
{
    blob = new PolygonClass();
}

blob.Load(memoryBlobStream);
IGeometry geometry = blob as IGeometry;
```

This solves my performance issue when trying to deserialize all the geometries of the table.

Comment: But I still didn't solve the fact that I haven't been able to save a persisted `IGeometry` to an `IObjectStream`.

Comment: A working compromise is still a victory. I'm glad that my ramblings pointed you in a useful direction, +1 from me and thank you for answering your own question *with code*.